# MySQL 5.1.73 in Oracle LINUX : Which is the correct mysql configuration file?

Tags: configuration, mysql, oracle-linux

I have installed **MySQL 5.1.73** manually by RPM on **Oracle LINUX 5**.
When I searched configuration file - **my.cnf** I run below command and get list of multiple configuration files.

$ locate *.cnf

```
/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
/u000/local/openssl/openssl.cnf
/u000/local/openssl/opensslnew.cnf
/usr/openv/pdde/pdopensource/ssl/openssl.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-community-5.1.73/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-community-5.1.73/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-community-5.1.73/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-community-5.1.73/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/doc/MySQL-server-community-5.1.73/my-small.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-huge.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-large.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf
/usr/share/mysql/my-small.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/include/default_mysqld.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/include/default_ndbd.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/std_data/bug15328.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/std_data/ndb_config_mycnf1.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/std_data/ndb_config_mycnf2.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/federated/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/ndb/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/rpl_1slave_base.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/t/rpl_circular_for_4_hosts.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/t/rpl_current_user.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/t/rpl_rotate_logs.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl/t/rpl_test_framework.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl_ndb/my.cnf
/usr/share/mysql-test/suite/rpl_ndb/t/rpl_ndb_circular_2ch.cnf
```

I am not sure which one is the correct configuration file which I have to modify? My application has 260 tables.

- So, should I also need to modify `my-large.cnf  or my-medium.cnf or my-small.cnf`?
- Should I need to move the selected configuration file in /etc/ directory?

Please advice...

Comment: Can this question be moved to dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Run `mysqld --verbose --help | less` and it will tell you near the top the locations and order in which it looks for `my.cnf` files. However the init script on your OS used to start mysql may override that behavior. More details on option files can be read in the mysql documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html